# Is it possible to highlight syntax in Notepad++ based on delimeters?

Tags: notepad++, syntax-highlighting

One of the applications we use spits out all of it's strings (for localization purposes) in a file where each line looks like this -

```
STRING_KEY[tab]the string[tab]comment[CRLF]
```

Is it possible to get Notepad++ (or possibly some other text editor) to highlight the different parts of the line based on where the tabs are?  I've tried to fight with the custom language definition functionality of N++ but it seems to be more focused on highlighting keywords and comment blocks and whatnot than what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I think the keyword you search is User Defined Language: http://udl20.weebly.com/

Comment: I've been messing around in the UDL2 dialog, but that only seems to have the ability to define syntax highlighting based on keywords and other forms of known text.  The actual contents of the file do not have any predefined keywords, all I know about the file before looking at it is the structure of the file.

Comment: That is basically a CSV file with tabs instead of commas. You could use CSV editor or something like LibreOffice Calc to edit the file.

Comment: Or open it in Microsoft Excel if you got an license

Comment: Thanks user694733, CSV editors seem to be the direction I want to be going :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone wrote a plugin called "csv-lint" to highlight CSV data-fields in NPP. It was released in 2021 (7 years after the question) and lets you choose the delimiters to separate the datafields. Hence it also works with [tab] and does exactly what the question asked for.

If not available online, you can use the plugin manager in NPP to install the plugin.

When you use it, make sure to:

- reformat the plugin setup to your files needs (Plugin -> CSV-Lint -> CSV-Lint window)
- then select "CSV-Lint" in the "Language" menu

https://github.com/BdR76/CSVLint

This seems to be the official announcment, and might help you further with the usage:

https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/22061/new-plugin-csv-lint

Comment: Red, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Ollie, thx for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

**If file format is CSV, then the answer is no in the N++.** (See "UPDATE" below for alternative.) Available syntax highlighter for user-defined languages is oriented on highlighting in computer languages. These usually do not follow the pattern you need for your task. As suggested by the above commenters, you should check dedicated CSV editors or Microsoft Excel (it has some pitfalls related to CSV editing, though - like stripping initial zeros in values which look like numbers).

---

**UPDATE:**
The following tip can help editing tricky parts of the CSV, especially quoted strings. It is also possible to implement highlighting or various columns in various colors (depending on their order), but I am not sure whether you still need it.

While it was impossible to implement correct quote matching in N++ lexer (fails on `"Test string"""`) it was easy to implement CSV lexer in Notepad++'s "cousin" called [SynWrite](http://www.uvviewsoft.com/synwrite/) which has advanced lexer capabilities.

Example: (quoted strings have separate style – notice multi-line strings and inner quotes)

[image]

Steps:

1. Create new lexer (menu *Options* > *Customize lexers library...*)
2. Switch to your new lexer (menu *View* > *Lexer*)
3. Customize your new lexer (menu *Options* > *Customize lexer...*)
4. On *Styles* tab, add new styles `String` and `Separator`, rename them below the list and customize their colors
5. On *Parser* tab, add item `String`

   - Token type: `String`
   - Token style: `String` (the one you added)
   - Regular expression: `"(""|[^"])*"`
6. On *Parser* tab, add item `Separator`

   - Token type: `Symbol`
   - Token style: `Separator` (the one you added)
   - Regular expression: `,`  (or `;` or `\t` (tab)... whatever you use in your CSV)

Confirm changes, you should be going.

Answer (score 0):

It won't be as helpful in this case, so its not a direct answer, but I find it quite useful in NPP, and MUCH easier, to just select "Python" or some similar language for CSV files.

Pound (aka sharp) signs code as comments, numbers as constants, quoted text as strings.

Its far from perfect, but it really beats staring at an uninterpretable mass of white on black. and often its really all I need.

Also, a reminder:  NPP can easily transform tab-delimited files, to other delimiters and back, so sometimes just a quick temporary edit can clarify things a lot.

Lastly, the *magnificent* TextFX plug-in, which is at LEAST 49% of why I use NPP can do awesome things with globs of "text".  If you haven't played around with that plug-in, you don't know what you are missing (ahem, literally).